# preloading a partial view in rails with javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

On a mouse click of a button, I switch out an image in a div with another partial in Rails. The problem is that loading the image in that partial is slow... I want to preload the image in it. Is there a way to do this? Can I preload the partial somehow?

## in my view

```
-@other_images.each do |img|
  .thumbnail_wrapper
    .thumbnail_image
      =image_tag img.image.url(:thumbnail), :class => 'button' , :onClick => "replaceImg(#{img.id});"
```

## js

```
function replaceImg(id){
  var url = '/images/refresh/' + id;
  new Ajax.Updater('content_image', url);
}
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your partial are renderd withint the view. Preloading is cheating the browser to make it sure it needs a resource, and it needs it now.

**Javascript**

You can force the images to preload before being actually shown in Javascript:

```
<script language="javascript">
function img_preloader() {
     myimg = new Image();
     images = new Array();
     images[0]="image1.jpg";
     images[1]="image2.jpg";
     images[2]="image3.jpg";
     images[3]="image4.jpg";

     // start preloading
     for(i=0; i<=3; i++) {
          myimg.src=images[i];
     }
} 
</script>
```

In this way for every iteration within the `for` loop one of your images are loaded.

To programmatically generate the array you can (in erb):

```
<script language="javascript">
function img_preloader() {
     myimg = new Image();
     images = new Array();
     <% @array_of_img_paths.each do |path| %>
     images.push("<%= path %>");
     <% end %>

     // start preloading
     for(i=0; i<images.length; i++) {
          myimg.src=images[i];
     }
} 
</script>
```

**Just HTML**

- programmatically open one iframe for every image you want to preload
- set the src of the iframe to the image you want to preload
- set the iframe size as tiny as possible

Now images are (pre)loaded in parallel according to the browser and server setup.

**CSS**

Set the image you want to preload as the background image of a div noone will ever see:

```
div.noone_will_see {
    background-image: url("image1.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: -1000px -1000px;
}
```

Iterate for every image you want to preload.

Comment: Hmm thank you, I know that much -- but I'm stuck because it's not quite so simple as doing 
images[0]="image1.jpg";
I'd rather do:
images[id]="image"+id+".jpg";
and to do this, I need to know the ids of the images on the page at the time (they vary). So I need to pass in my rails variable to this js function... I can't seem to make this work if the var is in a different .js file. So I was hoping to just render the partials directly. Gar.. sorry if this is a bit confusing.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. What's wrong with doing images[id]="image"+id+".jpg"? Iterate on evey id of the image you want to preload to create the js snippet within the HTML. Since the images may vay, the js will vary, so I cant see the point to have a shared js for different pages.

Comment: hey lbz, thanks for your response! Well, that does seem fine. but then how do I tell my js function what the id is? Sorry I'm a newbie -- right now, the id is stored in the rails variable @featured_image.id. When the page finishes loading, I want to somehow grab that variable and then tell my js function that this is the id, and increment from there. But I'm pulling my hairs out on how to do it. What am I missing?

Comment: ah! i posted a new question for what I feel like has grown into a new issues. any help of yours would be much, much appreciated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4294616/how-do-i-can-a-rails-variable-that-is-only-accessible-to-a-partial

Comment: Updated the answerm with a short example in erb. I am not into haml, maybe it can be translated somehow.